# how to navigate screen from App.js to first screen in React-Native

Tags: react-native

First of all sorry for this very ordinary question. I am new in React-Native.

I have used navigation in the app and I just add right button on the navigation bar for Log-Out from App.js. that code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View,SafeAreaView, ScrollView,Button,Alert} from 'react-native';
import PresentationalComponent from './PresentationalComponent'
import List from './List.js'
import Login from './Login.js'
import SignUp from './SignUp.js'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { useRoute } from '@react-navigation/native';
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
class App extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
 super(props);
}
logOutAction(){
  Alert.alert('Done!','Are you sure you want to log-out?',
      [{text: 'Cancel'},{text : 'Yes',onPress: this.done}]
      )
}
done(){
//alert(List.props.navigation.state.routeName)
}
render() {
  return (
  <NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} options={{ title: 'Log-In' }} />
    <Stack.Screen name="SignUp" component={SignUp} options={{ title: 'Sign-Up'}} />
    <Stack.Screen name="List" component={List} options={{ headerLeft:null, headerRight: () => (
        <Button
          onPress={() => this.logOutAction()}
          title="Log-Out"
          color="#000"
        />
      ) } }/>
  </Stack.Navigator>
 </NavigationContainer>
  );
  }
}
export default App;
```

My logout button action is exist in the App.js class. How to start app from Login.js when I click on Log-Out button?

Comment: How are you managing the login? you should conditionally render the stack based on the login status, check this out https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan thanks, user can login from login screen, once user login successfully than he navigate to List screen. And from the App.js I added the "Log-Out" button at the right side of navigation in List screen. So now when user click on that button and its action exist in the app.js class so how can I navigate at Login screen

Comment: Please check my answer

Comment: Checking same bro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access navigation from the header button you have to do like below

```
<Stack.Screen name="List" component={List} options={({navigation})=>({ headerLeft:null, headerRight: () => (
        <Button
          onPress={() => this.logOutAction(navigation)}
          title="Log-Out"
          color="#000"
        />
      )})}/>
```

So logoutAction would have access to navigation which you can use

```
logOutAction(navigation){
  Alert.alert('Done!','Are you sure you want to log-out?',
      [{text: 'Cancel'},{text : 'Yes',onPress:()=> this.done(navigation)}]
      )
}
done(navigation){
  navigation.navigate('Login');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I exactly want same!